# Modifying Google Maps API store locator to use JSON data in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, google-maps

I am looking for a solution to create a store locator using Google Maps API in WordPress. While there are numerous plugins for WordPress, I'm really looking for a more customized solution. Here are the parameters that are required:

- User can search for a location using their location (types in name, eg Leeds) or post/zip code.
- The initial search form is located on the home page and when submitted will redirect to the map page with nearest locations to them (based on a radius) with map pins for each of those locations
- If a user is already on the map page, the map will show with all available locations (11 locations in the United Kingdom)
- From the map page, users can also search their location to refine results
- Below the map, each of the locations will show as a tile (html) that includes information about each restaurant including the distance from your location
- Tiles will have links to a single page which has all info about said location
- This is being built on WordPress so my ideal set up would be one where each location is a WordPress page with an Advanced Custom Fields Google Map on the page

**What I've done**

So far, I have created locations using WordPress pages, with each page having its own ACF Google Map as a custom field. This gives all the locations on the map as required by using a custom loop to display all pages with maps.

I have then gone through the [example found here](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/intro) on Google's own documentation. I made a working copy of this using XML on a separate project, but I am now trying to do this using JSON.

**What I have so far**

Here is the code I have so far.

**Map page** - custom loop displays any locations I have set

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home */ 
get_header(); 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' -1,
        'post__in' => array( 8, 10 )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Search form here -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="addressInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location" />
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"/>
    <div class="acf-map">
        <?php
        while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 
        $location = get_field('location'); 
    ?>
        <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
     <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
     <p class="address"><?php echo $location['address']; ?></p>
     </div>
        <?php endwhile;
      ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

**The standard ACF Maps jquery with added functions from google maps store locator example** -- The main function here is the getUrl, which returns data from my JSON object

```
(function($) {

/*
*  new_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function new_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');


    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel : false
    };


    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
    searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = getUrl;

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];


    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });


    // center map
    center_map( map );


    // return
    return map;

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

/* Custom function to search locations */


function search_locations() {
var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
}

/*
The function from google maps example, but I don't know
How to modify this for my needs 

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
 // this could be a static value
 // var radius = 50; 
 // for example

 var radius = 50;

//  var searchUrl = http://localhost:8888/googlemaps/
 var searchUrl = 'storelocator.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
 getUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
     var id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
     var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
     var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
     var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     createMarker(latlng, name, address);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
   locationSelect.onchange = function() {
     var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
   };
 });
}
*/

// Basic Ajax call to return some data from my markers object
function getUrl(url) {
  var xhttp, jsonData, parsedData;

  // check that we have access to XMLHttpRequest
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

     jsonData = this.responseText;

     parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

     // test that we have some data
     parsedData.forEach(function(entry, index){
         console.log(entry.address);
     })

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", 'http://localhost:8888/googlemaps/markers', true);
  xhttp.send(null);
}



/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/
// global var
var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        // create map
        map = new_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

**The markers template, which shows creates all my markers as JSON** - this is the url I am calling in my AJAX request

```
<?php

    /* Template Name: Markers */

    // initialise an arrays
    $markers = array();
    $locations = array();


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' -1,
        'post__in' => array( 8, 10 )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query->have_posts()) :
    $counter = 0;
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        // the ACF custom field
        $location = get_field('location');
        // manually set radius
        $location['radius'] = 50;    

    foreach($location as $key => $value) {
        $locations[$key] = $value;
    }

    $markers[] = $locations;



        endwhile; 
    endif;

echo json_encode($markers);
```

When I click on the search button, the data is correctly logged to the console. My question now is, how can I modify the Google Store Locator example linked above so that I can then show the nearest locations to the users location?

I understand this is a long question with a lot of parts to it so if there's something I've not mentioned please ask me. Hopefully it all make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, I think you want only single result with least distance. 
This can be done by finding key in collection `markerNodes` having least distance. So we have to find that key first.

Here I am updating `searchLocationsNear(center)` function

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
  clearLocations();

  var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
  var searchUrl = 'storelocator.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
  var xml = parseXml(data);
  var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //First find element with least distance
  var minDisKey = 0; // assuming first element of markerNodes is minimum distance
  for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
    var minimum = parseFloat(markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("distance"));
    var value = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
    if(minimum > value) minDisKey = i;
  }
 // here we get element with least distance. 
 //So this key can be used for further processing with existing code.
    var id = markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("id");
    var name = markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("name");
    var name = markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("address");
    var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("distance"));
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markerNodes[minDisKey].getAttribute("lng")));

    createOption(name, distance, minDisKey);
    createMarker(latlng, name, address);
    bounds.extend(latlng);

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
 });
}
```

After applying this you can get only one result which is nearest.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but that wasn't quite what I was looking for. I think I haven't explained it well.

Comment: So what was you looking for. Can you update the post.